# save data in a json flie without overwriting existing file in python

Tags: arrays, json, python-3.x

i need to add data in an json file without overwriting.

the code am using is:

```
import json

data=[]

def arr():
    x=0
    while x<1:
        print(x)
        x-=1
        X.append(x)
        data.update(x)
        with open('x.txt','w')as outfile:
            json.dump(data,outfile)


arr()
print(X)
```

this one works file.But,while am running this code second time it overwrites the existing values in the text file.help me to solve this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to append data to the file each time you run this code, you need to use the append mode.

Your code:

```
with open('x.txt','w')as outfile:
```

should be

```
with open('x.txt','a')as outfile:
```

The `'w'` mode (or the write mode) will cause you to overwrite to the file, whereas the `'a'` mode (or the append mode) will let you append data to the file.

Learn more about this here:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp

Comment: this simply appends JSON to the JSON so that you end up with something like `{...original...}{...appended...}`, which obviously creates invalid JSON....

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm like 3 years too late to answer but for anyone else having the same problem then feel free to continue reading!

The code:

```
with open("json.json", "r") as f:
    users = json.load(f)

foo = users["some data"]

variable = foo

variable.extend(your list)

users["some data"] = variable

with open("json.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(users, f)
```

That should work, I didn't test it before hand.

Answer (score 0):

youll want to use a try and except to see if the file can be read, then if not it can be created, information with a json has to be overwritten but this can be done when running the program, you can read the entire json file store it to a value, then write the json containing the old information with the new.Try and except will be used to check if the file exists rather then re-writting the file each time the program is ran.

Comment: A bit of code to exemplify what you mean wouldn't hurt

Answer (score -1):

What you want is write to file in Append mode.

This will solve your overwriting issue. use the write method.

```
with open("x.txt", "a") as outfile:
    outfile.write("new text")
```